# Choosing spatial statistical tool in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-statistics, references

When using Esri's Spatial Statistics toolbox I find the tables on the [Spatial Statistics toolbox sample applications](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/spatial-statistics-toolbox-sample-applications.htm) page to be very useful.  However, there are multiple rows in the tables where multiple tools are listed (e.g. Hot Spot, Optimized Hot Spot, or Local Moran's I and OLS or GWR). Some of the distinctions are straightforward but some are much more nuanced.

Is anyone aware of a resource that would help distinguish between these tools?

Answer (score 5):

1. [Spatial Statistics Resources](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/07/13/spatial-statistics-resources/) or https://spatialstats.github.io/. This page made in 2010 in the esri blog,But esri update it when a new resource availabled.
2. [The ESRI Guide to GIS Analysis, Volume 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/158948116X). THis book describe ArcGIS spatial statistic tools and algorithms with many examples.**The best resource to learn basics of spatial statistics and it's practical.**
3. [Spatial Analytics with ArcGIS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1787122581). A new book about Analyze patterns, clusters, and spatial relationships using ArcGIS tools By Eric Pimpler. It's a complete practical source.
4. [GIS Tutorial for Crime Analysis (GIS Tutorials)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/158948214X).You learn hotspot analysis  practically with ArcGIS tools.
5. without learning basics of statistics you can't understand the differences between these methods. One of the good books to learn basic of statistics is [Statistical Methods for Geography](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1848600038)
6. If you want to be a Spatial statistics pro, Learn **R** software and relationship between R and ArcGIS.Eric Pimpler Book has some examples about R and ArcGIS relations.A known book about R and spatial anaysis is [An Introduction to R for Spatial Analysis and Mapping](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1446272958). I didn't read this book but customers review in Amazon show the quality of this book.

Comment: The resources here are all good but, it is important to actually read the primary literature and not just rely on cookbooks. The OP gives no indication as the the nature of their data. As such we do not even know if any of the ESRI tools are appropriate. Very often, these tools are used on data that is not at all appropriate for the given statistic. Basic understanding of the statistic(s) and assumptions is imperative and I am not certain that these resources provide that foundation. What about the Cressie, Fortin & Dale, Bivand, Baddeley & Turner, Illan, etc.. books?

Comment: I think these resources are comprehensive because These resources focus on Spatial statistics theories and application in ArcGIS and Esri recommend 1 and 2 for it's users.  If the users want to be a pro in Spatial statistics, there are many many resources to  deep into this world and find some specific spatial statistics softwares. But this question is about Spatial statistics in ArcGIS software.